# Sparse matrix nonzero count in Eigen 3.3

Tags: eigen

In Eigen 3.2 sparse matrices had a method named 'nonZeros' that returned the count of non-zero elements. This method seems to be gone in Eigen 3.3. How does one obtain the number of nonzero in 3.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still there. In `Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseCompressedBase.h` line 56 there is one definition (for `SparseCompressedBase`).

```
template<typename Derived>
class SparseCompressedBase
  : public SparseMatrixBase<Derived>
{
  ...
  protected:
    typedef typename Base::IndexVector IndexVector;
    Eigen::Map<IndexVector> innerNonZeros() { return Eigen::Map<IndexVector>(innerNonZeroPtr(), isCompressed()?0:derived().outerSize()); }
    const  Eigen::Map<const IndexVector> innerNonZeros() const { return Eigen::Map<const IndexVector>(innerNonZeroPtr(), isCompressed()?0:derived().outerSize()); }

  public:

    /** \returns the number of non zero coefficients */
    inline Index nonZeros() const
    {
      if(Derived::IsVectorAtCompileTime && outerIndexPtr()==0)
        return derived().nonZeros();
```

More so, a quick grep shows all the definitions (v3.3.0):

> $ grep -rn "Index nonZeros()" *
>   src/Core/DenseBase.h:210:    inline Index nonZeros() const { return size(); }
>   src/SparseCore/AmbiVector.h:39:    Index nonZeros() const;
>   src/SparseCore/SparseBlock.h:42:    Index nonZeros() const
>   src/SparseCore/SparseBlock.h:436:    Index nonZeros() const { return Dynamic; }
>   src/SparseCore/SparseCompressedBase.h:56:    inline Index nonZeros() const
>   src/SparseCore/SparseMap.h:87:    inline Index nonZeros() const { return m_zero_nnz[1]; }
>   src/SparseCore/SparseTranspose.h:31:    inline Index nonZeros() const { return derived().nestedExpression().nonZeros(); }
>   src/SparseCore/SparseVector.h:140:    inline Index nonZeros() const  { return m_data.size(); }

Comment: To complete, it's true that in 3.3 nonZeros() have been removed from some expressions for which nonZeros could only returns a coarse estimate.